# How to convert BinData and display Image at react Front end?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, image, base64, blob

I have to Display Images at react front end which is currently in BinData Format from MongoDB and what I got [this in response object and response.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA5VM.png) Now I have Passed the Binary Data in src attribute of img element with mimetype and data encoding type.

```
    <img src = {'data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.responseData}'} />
```

But it did not worked. I tried to use Blob, File and Filereader object as well but nothing worked.
[Here is the Object Values I have logged on Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QxOi.png)

I also Tried using Buffer but that too didn't worked [Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmMue.png)
Here is my front end code

```
    componentDidMount() {
    const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8103/api/display_posts', { 'username' : localStorage.getItem('username')}, {headers})
        .then(res => {
            const responseData= res.data;
            console.log(res)
            console.log(responseData)

            const blobData = new Blob([responseData] , {
                type: "image/jpeg"
            })
            console.log(blobData);
            

            const myFile = new File([blobData], 'image.jpeg', {
                type: blobData.type,
            });
            console.log(myFile);

            const blob= new FileReader();
            blob.onload = function(){
                var dataURL = blob.result;
                var output = document.getElementById('here');
                output.src = dataURL;
            }
            blob.readAsDataURL(blobData);
            console.log(blob);

            const bufff =new Buffer(responseData, "binary").toString('base64');
            console.log(bufff)
            
            const bufff2 =new Buffer(responseData, "base64").toString('base64');
            console.log(bufff2)
            
            const buffer=Buffer.from(responseData, "base64");
            console.log(buffer);
            const desh = fs.writeFileSync("abc.jpg", buffer);
        

            this.setState({
                picture1: bufff,
                picture2: bufff2,
                picture3: responseData,
            });
            
        })
        .catch(
            (error) => console.log(error)
        )
}render(){
    return(
        <>
            <div>
                {this.state.respo}
                <img id="here"/>
                <img src = {'data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.picture1}'} /> 
                <img src = {'data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.picture2}'} /> 
                <img src = {'data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.picture3}'} />
```

This is how I am sending image stored in fs.chunks in MongoDB Database using Flask App.

```
    postImage = self.Posts.objects(username=self.content['username']).only('background').first()

    
    
    bgImage=postImage.background
    filename = postImage.background.filename
    content_type = postImage.background.content_type
    return send_file(bgImage, download_name=filename, mimetype=content_type), 200
```

What am I doing Wrong?
I think the Image is stored in Base64 format in fs.chunks collection [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiPLt.png)
But sending it on front end it is converted back into [Binary Bytes Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1yV3.png)
Now it can be converted back into base64 using btao() & Buffer+toString()

```
    const buffer= new Buffer.from(responseData);
    const vd= buffer.toString('base64');
    console.log(vd);
    const cc= window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(responseData)));
    console.log(cc);
```

But it's also not working as I got to know that in Opera 11 and older versions their is a limited URLs to 65535 characters long which limits data URLs to 65529 characters (65529 characters being the length of the encoded data, not the source, if you use the plain data:, without specifying a MIME type)[Read Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)
And also the 100KB image became 247kB. Please Suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

JS have btoa() function for it.

You can do that like

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa('your-binary-data');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Read about it here [BTOA](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/btoa)

also if your binary wasn't valid , you need to convert it

```
function hexToBase64(str) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
}
```

and use it instead

```
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + hexToBase64('your-binary-data');
```

Comment: Opera 11 and older versions their is a limited URLs to 65535 characters long which limits data URLs to 65529 characters (65529 characters being the length of the encoded data, not the source, if you use the plain data:, without specifying a MIME type) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs

Comment: No sir, even this is not Working I have tried hexToBase64()function as well. Is their any problem at the backend(flask app). I have added the Flask Code recently please check it.

Comment: btoa("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100") it will create base64 string from binary string , atob doing reverse , I don't understand your problem ,send me example of binary , what are you trying to do ? @AkshatJain

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change response type

```
const config = { responseType: 'blob' };
axios.get(blobUrl, config).then(response => {
    new File([response.data], fileName);       
});
```

Comment: Okay! What's the right way to store images in MongoDB database or local folder

Comment: My opinion is that , MongoDB is not a good place for storing files. If you want to store files, you should use storages like Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage, or other storages.

The good practice is to store the files in a storage and then to just save the URL of the uploaded image in the MongoDB. @AkshatJain